# To thin chocolate candy coating, how much oil to use?

Tags: chocolate

I am trying to use chocoate candy coating on chocolate transfer sheets. The normal chunk of chocolate candy coating is too thick when melted, so I used vegetable oil to thin it for better spreading.

I used 1:2.5 ratio for this, 20ml oil for 50ml chocolate. It was thin and soft enough for spreading and hardens nicely in the refridgerator.

The problem is, however, that it stays soft and even a little bit runny at room temperature :(

I don't think this is a problem if my chocolates stay in the fridge but it will be problematic when stored outside.

Is my ratio off? Any other tricks you can suggest? Or if you have a golden ratio of your own please share!

P.S.: I used a kroger brand white chocolate candy coating

(SUGAR (SUGAR, CORN STARCH), PARTIALLY HYDROGENATED PALM KERNAL OIL, COCOA PROCESSED WITH ALKALI, CORN SYRUP SOLIDS, NONFAT DRY MILK, MILK POWDER, COCOA, SOY LECITHIN (AN EMULSIFIER), NATURAL FLAVORS.)

Comment: I have a hard time imagining a good answer to your question, because I can't pinpoint your goal. There is no "golden ratio" which is good for any case, because each ratio leads to a different consistency. Maybe you can describe in more detail what final consistency you need? Else nobody can guess how much less oil you need.

Answer (score 5):

Yes your ratio is off. After melting if your coating is too thick add vegetable shortening (Crisco) a little at a time until you reach the desired consistency. Start with a tablespoon per pound and add just enough to get to the consistency you need. Crisco is solid at room temperature unlike veg. oil so your final product shouldn't have to stay in the fridge.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, I +1'd the answer about crisco, but I've had some trouble with that method in the past when I made cakepops. Even with oil-based food coloring (Americolor brand if you're wondering), my white chocolate started seizing up a bit, and I used too much crisco trying to compensate. While the chocolate did solidify at room temperature, it took forever, which might not cause a problem in itself, but in the case of my cakepops the coating continued to run down the sticks and made a mess.

I spent some time googling to figure out an option besides crisco, and wound up at "paramount crystals," which sound magical. I have not used them, but [Amazon reviews](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001JXDXG) indicate that chocolate moderated with paramount crystals dried quickly and hard.